# Passing a pointer to MPI_Win_allocate_shared through a wrapper

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, mpi

I am having some difficulties to understand what is going on with my pointer passings:

I have the following minimal program

```
#include <mpi.h>
void ALLOC_SHM(double * arr, int sz);
void MPI_WRAP( MPI_Aint size, int disp, MPI_Comm comm, double * bufptr, MPI_Win* win ) ;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   int size, whoami;
   double* arr;
   MPI_Init(NULL, NULL) ;
   MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size ); 
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &whoami);
   
   ALLOC_SHM(arr, 1000); 
   
   
   return 0;
}


void ALLOC_SHM(double * arr, int sz)
{
   MPI_Win win; 
   MPI_Aint size = sz*sizeof(double);
   int disp = sizeof(double);
   printf("in alloc before mpi_wrap: %p\n", arr);
   MPI_WRAP(size, disp, MPI_COMM_WORLD, arr, &win);  
   printf("in alloc AFTER mpi_wrap: %p\n", arr);

   return;
}


void MPI_WRAP( MPI_Aint size, int disp, MPI_Comm comm, double * bufptr, MPI_Win* win ) 

{
   printf("in mpi_wrap before WIN_ALLOC: %p\n", bufptr);
   int ierr = MPI_Win_allocate_shared( size, disp, MPI_INFO_NULL, comm, &bufptr, win );
   printf("in mpi_wrap AFTER WIN_ALLOC: %p\n", bufptr);
   return;
}
```

My points of doubts:

1. The call to the MPI_WRAP is wrong, but why? Is it because the MPI Api expects an address to the pointer (i.e. `**arr`)
2. If that above reason is correct, then it can be solved by passing the address to the pointer so my CALL is `MPI_WRAP(size, disp,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &arr, &win);`
3. Now if that is correct (2), I accidentally realised that my code did not have a problem running it while NOT changing my `MPI_WRAP` interface. But clearly, I am not passing a pointer (`*bufptr`), but rather a `**buftr`. I then changed my `MPI_WRAP` interface to the following  `MPI_WRAP( MPI_Aint size, int disp, MPI_Comm comm, double ** bufptr, MPI_Win* win )` (I am changing it to a double pointer, and still calling it using as done in (2) ). That did surprisingly also work. I have worked long enough with MPI to know that just because it works now, does not mean it is right - and you are just lucky it works for your case - Hence, What is going on here, how come I can consider both interfaces and they both seem to work?

Comment: Even if the argument is `void *baseptr`, it really should be interpreted as a `void **baseptr` (refer to the MPI standard for the rationale). You should hence pass `&arr` to your wrapper (or use a reference).

Comment: That did not help. Inside AllocMethod::Alloc I passed `&arr`. Still facing same problem. After the call to the mpi wrapper I printed the pointer address to arr and still get 0x0 while within the mpi wrapper I get a valid address

Comment: Please edit your question with a [MCVE] and I will have a look.

Comment: I added the main.cpp as well. Everything now should be sufficient to run. But FYI, when I passed `&arr` within my `AllocMethod::Alloc` I did not work. But when I then also removed the `&` from when calling `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` - that seemed to work. But I am not sure, because when I for example, change the interface of my wrapper to ` Win_allocate_shared(MPI_Aint nbytes, const int disp,double** arr, MPI_Win* win) ` (double pointer) it also seems to work. But I suppose that at least one of them is incorrect

Comment: If your problem is not fixed, please really post a [MCVE] (e.g. a single source file that compiles and run)

Comment: Thanks @GillesGouaillardet. This example above runs on my computer using MPICH with clang++.  and it reproduces my initial issue.

Comment: If I correctly interpret the changes you made (but did not post), you basically do `double *arr; void * bufptr = &arr;`. (Implicitly) casting a `double **` into a `void *` might look counter intuitive at first glance, but this is the right thing to do here: as long as you pass `&arr` and do not dereference it, it does not matter if you declare the subroutine argument(s) as a `double **` or a `void *`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I am not using `void *` anywhere. I don't think I understand were you answers, can you please clarify it to me. I have edited the question exactly to this now

Comment: `void *` is the type of `bufptr` in `MPI_Win_allocate_shared()` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some reading of the MPI standard and understanding of C++ pointers and function arguments may help here. For example, reading the Open MPI manual page for [`MPI_Win_allocate_shared`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man3/MPI_Win_allocate_shared.3.php):

> On each process, it allocates memory of at least *size* bytes that is shared among all processes in *comm*, and **returns a pointer to the locally allocated segment in *baseptr*** that can be used for load/store accesses on the calling process.

The only way for a C++ function to return a value through a function argument is if that argument is a reference or a pointer to a location for the value. Therefore, although the manual page lists `baseptr` as `void *`, it is really of type `void **`.

Now, the difference between:

```c
void foo(void *bar) {
   MPI_Win_allocate_shared(..., &bar, ...);
}

void *baz;
foo(baz);
```

and

```c
void foo(void **bar) {
   MPI_Win_allocate_shared(..., bar, ...);
}

void *baz;
foo(&baz);
```

Although in both cases the call to `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` ends up having a `void **` as an argument, the former case is conceptually wrong. You are not passing the address of `baz`, but rather a pointer to the formal argument `bar`, which holds a **copy** of the value of `baz`. The semantics of formal arguments is basically that of local variables initialised with the actual function argument:

```c
void *bar = baz;
MPI_Win_allocate_shared(..., &bar, ...);
```

This writes a new value into `bar` while leaving the value of `baz` unchanged. Which is why you see a new value after the call to `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` inside `MPI_WRAP` but the old value once it returns to the calling function.

The latter is akin to

```c
void **bar = &baz;
MPI_Win_allocate_shared(..., bar, ...);
```

This has totally different semantics. `bar` now contains the address of `baz` and that's the location `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` writes the address of the allocated buffer into.

So the correct C/C++ code is:

```c
void foo(void **bar) {
   MPI_Win_allocate_shared(..., bar, ...);
}

void *baz;
foo(&baz);
```

C++ has references and the same can be written like so:

```c
void foo(void *&bar) {
   MPI_Win_allocate_shared(..., &bar, ...);
}

void *baz;
foo(baz);
```

This is very similar to the first (incorrect) case, with the crucial difference that here the formal argument `bar` is an alias of the actual argument `baz`, so now `&bar` is the same as `&baz`. Hence, `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` will write the return value into the storage space of `baz`.

A side note: I recommend the manual pages from Open MPI because the explanations there are basically excerpts from the MPI standard.

Comment: I think I just realised something. The address of a pointer needs to be passed, because if not, the function will create a local copy of the pointer address hence, it will go out of scope once the function returns?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You need to pass a pointer to the pointer in order to be able to modify the value of the pointer. Or a reference, as in my last example.